# How to Hide keyboard when activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard

I have an activity with lots of edittext. whenever I load that activity, the keyboard appears and eats half of the screen which makes that activity's look bad. So is there any way to hide keyboard when I load that activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide Soft Keyboard when activity starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

in your onCreate() use this..

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: @CautionContinues, SudiptaforAndroid,Amitabha Biswas. Thanks, Happy Coding.!

Answer (score 9):

Add this two line in your activity's XML file in the RootLayout i.e. either relative or linear(whatever you have taken)  :

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Add this line in activity manifests file

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 8):

In your AndroidManifest.xml add the attribute  **android:windowSoftInputMode**:

```
<activity android:name="your.package.ActivityName"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using intputmethodmangare... using the following code..

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on the `onCrete` function:

`new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
  InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
  view.clearFocus();
}}, 50);`

where `view` is your EditText

The runnable is because the code might be executed before the `editText` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method which I call in all the required Activity classes in the onCreate event. Worked for me in all scenarios.

```
public class ClassLib {
        public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        //Hide keyboard
        activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```