# How to hide Soft Keyboard when activity starts

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an Edittext with `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` in Manifest. Now the keyboard will be shown when I start the activity. How to hide it? I cannot use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden` because when keyboard is visible then minimize the app and resume it the keyboard should be visible. 
I tried with

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);`

but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If you don't want to use xml, make a Kotlin Extension to hide keyboard

```
// In onResume, call this
myView.hideKeyboard()

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Alternatives based on use case:

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    view?.let { activity?.hideKeyboard(it) }
}

fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    // Calls Context.hideKeyboard
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    view.hideKeyboard()
}
```

#### How to ***show*** soft keyboard

```
fun Context.showKeyboard() { // Or View.showKeyboard()
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(SHOW_FORCED, HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
}
```

Simpler method when simultaneously requesting focus on an edittext

```
myEdittext.focus()

fun View.focus() {
    requestFocus()
    showKeyboard()
}
```

#### Bonus simplification:

Remove requirement for ever using `getSystemService`: [Splitties Library](https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties/tree/master/modules/systemservices)

```
// Simplifies above solution to just
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
```

Answer (score 381):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

or try

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)‌​;
```

Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) also

Comment: Thanks for  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Comment: Actually there is also great answer on preventing focusing on the edit text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity

Answer (score 208):

Use the following functions to show/hide the keyboard:

```
/**
 * Hides the soft keyboard
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the soft keyboard
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Comment: Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE for those who are in fragments or are not in the main activity etc.

Comment: You can try this. It works if you call it from the activity. getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)‌​;

Comment: What if we need to call this from within a listener? Like `onFocusChange()`

Answer (score 48):

Just add two attributes to the parent view of editText.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 37):

Put this in the manifest inside the  Activity tag

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: or android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" - This works like: don't show it if it isn't already shown, but if it was open when entering the activity, leave it open).

Comment: ya you are correct . but what if the orientation changed ?

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
    ...
>
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037375/how-to-keep-soft-keyboard-from-opening-on-activity-launch-in-android) one for more details.

Answer (score 13):

To hide the softkeyboard at the time of New Activity start or `onCreate()`,`onStart()` etc. you can use the code below:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 12):

Using **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  
 />
```

Using **Java**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

using the above solution keyboard hide but edittext from taking focus when activiy is created, but grab it when you touch them using:

add in your **EditText**

```
<EditText
android:focusable="false" />
```

also add listener of your EditText

```
youredittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.setFocusable(true);
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    return false;
}});
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the following text to your xml file.

```
<!--Dummy layout that gain focus -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

I hope this will work, I tried a lot of methods but this one worked for me in `fragments`. just put this line in onCreateview/init.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 6):

add in your activity in manifasts 
this property

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 5):

Put this code your java file and pass the argument for object on edittext,

```
private void setHideSoftKeyboard(EditText editText){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To hide the softkeyboard at the time of New Activity start or onCreate(),onStart() method etc. use the code below:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

To hide softkeyboard at the time of Button is click in activity:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        assert imm != null;
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN instead of SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 5):

Above answers are also correct. I just want to give a brief that there's two ways to hide the keyboard when starting the activity, from manifest.xml. 
eg:

```
<activity
..........
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
..........
/>
```

- The above way always hide it when entering the activity.

or

```
<activity
..........
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
..........
/>
```

- This one says don't change it (e.g. don't show it if it isn't already shown, but if it was open when entering the activity, leave it open).

Answer (score 4):

You can set config on AndroidManifest.xml

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code to Hide the softkeyboard first time when you start the Activity

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one also

```
Ed_Cat_Search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Searc_Categories);

Ed_Cat_Search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Ed_Cat_Search.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Ed_Cat_Search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        Ed_Cat_Search.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        return true; // consume touch even
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

```
yourEditText.setCursorVisible(false); //This code is used when you do not want the cursor to be visible at startup
        yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.onTouchEvent(event);   // handle the event first
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {

                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);  // hide the soft keyboard
                    yourEditText.setCursorVisible(true); //This is to display cursor when upon onTouch of Edittext
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

If your application is targeting **Android API Level 21 or more** than there is a default method available.

```
editTextObj.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Make sure you have set below code in `EditText` XML tag.

```
<EditText  
    ....
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

First in your searchable xml the fields (name and hint etc) put `@string` and not literal strings.

Then method `onCreateOptionsMenu`, it must have a `ComponentName` object with your package name and your completed class name (with package name) - In case  activity which has the `SearchView` component is the same as the show search results use `getComponentName()`, as the google android developer says.

I tried a lot of solutions and after much,much work this solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ed_Cat_Search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Searc_Categories);

Ed_Cat_Search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Ed_Cat_Search.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Ed_Cat_Search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        Ed_Cat_Search.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
        return true; // consume touch even
    }
});

this one worked for me
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

it will works

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.