# Android edittext and virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where there are edit text, but I have a problem because the virtual keyboard automatically appears.

I wonder if there is not a way that it does not automatically appears but only when you click on a Edit Text

Comment: do you aware of the `<requestfocus>` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide Soft Keyboard when activity starts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#ShowOnStart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in your `Activity`. The keyboard will only open when you click on it

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the Manifest for your activity: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`. For example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.proj.activity.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in **onResume()** method then the keyboard will not popup automatically...

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void showKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus()
            .getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your EditText to respond to focus change event, and hide keyboard manually,

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener
{
    protected void onCreate( Bundle b )
    {
         .....
        txtX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_x);
        txtX.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(View view)
    {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean arg1)
    {
        if(! view.hasFocus())
            hideKeyboard(view);
    }
}
```

and in xml set your layout to focusable

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```