# Hide the on-screen keyboard on button press

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm wondering how best to hide the on-screen (soft?) keyboard after the user pushes a button. They keyboard will likely still be visible as the user is entering text before submitting it, I'd like to shrink the window on their submission.

I have found answers to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts) but neither seem to properly work. They keyboard is still visible, though Toast notifications are displayed on top.

My code, for clarity:

```
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And I have also tried:

```
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtToWrite)).getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS?

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

I think you can also try clearing the focus from the EditText/SearchView too. For example:

```
searchBar = (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.ditto_search_bar);
searchBar.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Yes, I had found that and it worked. Thank you for your reply and my apologies for a late accept.