# how to hide keyboard when Application launch or remove focus?

Tags: android

[image]

hello
I make simple application when I run that application my keyboard open automatically I want to remove focus from edit field or hide keyboard first time when application launch

here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/top_header"
        layout="@layout/header_second_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_item"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
        android:background="#ee3333">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/entry"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:hint="Add Name"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#567234"
                android:text="Login"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_item"
        layout="@layout/footer_second_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this link will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: put it into android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  activity in manifest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide Soft Keyboard when activity starts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts)

Answer (score 4):

You can hide keyboard when your activity launches.

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

or try

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)‌​;
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

A simpler trick.

Just add the following XML attributes to your root `RelativeView`. Actually you need to make sure the view you're adding these attributes to is placed **before** the first `EditText`.

```
<RelativeLayout
...
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
...
> ... </RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide your keyboard

```
public static void hideKeyboard( Activity activity ) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
        View f = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if( null != f && null != f.getWindowToken() && EditText.class.isAssignableFrom( f.getClass() ) )
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( f.getWindowToken(), 0 );
        else 
            activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );
    }
```