# Editext keyboard visibility on off programmatically Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I am new to Android. I have one edit text when I click on it keyboard is showing automatically. But what I want to do is when user double tab on edit text should show the keyboard. How can I achieve it?

```
 <Edit Text
            android:id="@+id/TV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type something"/>
```

Here I take simple edit text.I take one Gesture Listener class to achieve double tap listener event.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `OnLongClickListener` to achive what you want?

```
yourEditText .setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //show your keyboard
                return false;
            }
        });
```

hide soft keyboard when click on edit text

```
  yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }       

            }
        });
```

Here also read this post [Android: How to detect double-tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/android-how-to-detect-double-tap) may help you to understand

Comment: i just want to stop automatically open keyboard when i simply click on edittext but i dont know how to achive it.

Comment: check my edit answer i tell me if you succeed. Hope to help you.

Comment: no its not working still opens keyboard on single click

Comment: Yes, it will not work because imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0); is a toggle behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code, it will check that the edittext is opened or not. If it is opened it will close it

```
     yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yourEditText= this.getCurrentFocus();
            if (yourEditText!= null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```