# Hide soft keyboard when on new page

Tags: java, android

I have an application with an EditText element on the next view. This means that when my application is loaded the soft keyboard appears per default.

What code do I use to hide this keyboard on IntelliJ?

**UPDATE**

Comment: Hi, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977227/4483200

Comment: Duplicate: The amount of time it took you to write this question could have been used to do a little research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way

in your `onCreate()`

```
   this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode
    (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Sometimes this won't work. 
So what you can do is, make your `editText` -> `focusable` as `false` inside your `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

For Hiding keyboard, you can have two ways:

**Either:** (This will hide the keyboard on app/activity launch)
put this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in activity tag of related activity in manifest.xml as:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

**Or:**
put this method in your activity and call it whenever you have to hide the keyboard.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    public void hideKeyBoard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

and call it as `hideKeyBoard(view);`.

Remember, you have to pass the view to hide the keyboard as above.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method for showing and hiding keyboard, called from an activity or fragment

```
public void hideKeyboard(final boolean hide) {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) {
        return;
    }
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (hide) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    } else {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> imm.showSoftInput(view, 0), 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest put  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" under your activity on which you want to hide soft keyboard like:

```
    <activity android:name=".Viewschedule"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
```

OR

```
   InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imgr.showSoftInput(view, 0);
```