# Hide keyboard on activity start on SearchView not working

Tags: android, focus, searchview

I have a situation where I open `SearchActivity` and I want to have cursor in `SearchView` (keeping focus) while not showing keyboard at first. When and ONLY when user presses `SearchView` I want to show keyboard (cursor should be intact)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide Soft Keyboard when activity starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts)

Comment: just hide keyboard when activity starts

Answer (score 2):

Add this below line in your `activity.xml` file's main layout

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    ...
   >
```

Comment: `SearchView` has focus, but keyboard still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `Manifest` inside `SearchActivity`

```
<activity name=".SearchActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

or In Activity `onCreate()` add

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: `SearchView` has focus, but keyboard still appears.

Comment: I've updated answer, try with stateHidden or code approach

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `SearchActivity` in `onCreate`

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)‌​;
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your onCreate to hide the kayboard

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you used below code to show key board..

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(searchView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and close keyboard used this ...

```
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta hide the softkeyboard after the SearchView gets focus:

```
search.postDelayed({
        val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view?.windowToken, 0)
    }, 100)
```